# `reindex-chainstate` configuration in bitcoin.conf?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin.conf, reindex

Is there a specific flag I can place in bitcoin.conf to reindex the chainstate (not command line)?

Ie:
reindex=1 does a full reindex is there a flag like
reindex-chainstate=1 or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All command line options can be specified in the bitcoin.conf file using the same name without the leading dash (`-`). For `-reindex-chainstate`, you add `reindex-chainstate=1` to your bitcoin.conf.

Note that putting options into the config will run them every time you start Bitcoin Core. In the case of `reindex-chainstate`, you really want to only use the flag once—you do not need to start with reindexing every time you restart Bitcoin Core. So be sure to remove any options that you only wanted to run once after restarting Bitcoin Core the first time.

Comment: Though, you really shouldn't. It's something you should only pass once. If you put it in your bitcoin.conf, it'll start over with reindexing every time you restart.